# Decorate path and its edges with pathmorphing decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, pgf-decorations

I'd like to define a TikZ style that applies a path morphing decoration to a path as well every of its edges, just like the `dashed` style is applied to all edges.
Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{
mysnake/.style={postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=1pt,segment length=3pt}}},
allsnake/.style={mysnake,every edge/.style=mysnake},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% works
\path[mysnake] (0,0)--++(1,0);
% compiles but doesn't decorate
\path[mysnake] (0,0.4)edge[]++(1,0);
% decorates both the path and the edges
\path[allsnake] (0,0.8)edge[]++(1,0) (0,1.2)--++(1,0);
% this is fine as well:
\path[allsnake] (0,1.6)edge[]++(1,0);
% this doesn't compile though:
\node[draw] (x) at (0,2){a};
\path[allsnake] (x)edge[]++(1,0);
% this doesn't compile either:
\path[mysnake] (x)edge[]++(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The last two lines in the `tikzpicture` environment give an error: "ERROR: Package pgf Error: I cannot decorate an empty path."
The output with the last two lines commented is:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this, or how to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: In your code, you say one of the lines decorates the path and its edges. Isn't that what you want? How is what you're trying to do different?

Comment: @crf: Yes, it does what I want, but it throws an error when applied to a path with an edge that starts at a node.

Comment: @cfr (sorry, mistyped your username)

Comment: I got pinged anyway because I'm the only other one here. (At least, I think that's why. The rules are difficult to figure out at times.)

Comment: I get a problem with `\path[mysnake] (0,0) ++(1,0);`.  Somewhere, the fact that `(x)` is a node rather than a coordinate means that when TikZ gets to the point where it is considering decorating the path then it doesn't know that the path is empty, probably because the `(x)` hasn't been resolved into a specific position.  So it thinks that the path is not empty, tries to decorate it, but then runs into problems because the path actually is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be that with a bare node used as a coordinate, as in `(x)`, then a non-trivial path is constructed and so the decoration is activated.  However, that non-trivial path just consists of move-tos and so there is nothing to decorate.

I'm not too clear on how exactly this happens (my attempts at diagnosing exactly where the non-trivial path exists have come to naught), but here's some code that puts in an extra check to see if the path has some drawable components prior to decorating it.  This uses my `spath3` library, but needs to use some commands that aren't at the "user level", hence the `\ExplSyntaxO[n|ff]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/699313/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,spath3}
\tikzset{
  mysnake/.style={
    postaction={
      draw,
      only if drawable={decorate},
      decoration={
        snake,
        amplitude=1pt,
        segment length=3pt
      }
    }
  },
  allsnake/.style={
    mysnake,
    every edge/.style=mysnake
  },
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tikzset{
  only~ if~ drawable/.code={
    \tl_set:Nn \l__tikzspath_tikzpath_finish_tl
    {
      \spath_get_current_path:N \l__tikzspath_tmpa_tl
      \spath_bake_round:NV \l__tikzspath_tmpa_tl \l__tikzspath_tmpa_tl
      \spath_bake_shorten:NV \l__tikzspath_tmpa_tl \l__tikzspath_tmpa_tl
      \spath_reallength:NV \l__tikzspath_tmpa_int \l__tikzspath_tmpa_tl
      \int_compare:nNnT {\l__tikzspath_tmpa_int} > {0}
      {
        \tikzset{#1}
      }
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% works
\path[mysnake] (0,0)--++(1,0);
% compiles but doesn't decorate
\path[mysnake] (0,0.4)edge[]++(1,0);
% decorates both the path and the edges
\path[allsnake] (0,0.8)edge[]++(1,0) (0,1.2)--++(1,0);
% this is fine as well:
\path[allsnake] (0,1.6)edge[]++(1,0);
% this doesn't compile though:
\node[draw] (x) at (0,2){a};
\path[allsnake] (x)edge[]++(1,0);
% this doesn't compile either:
\node[draw] (y) at (0,2.4){b};
\path[mysnake] (y)edge[]++(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Various decorated lines]

What's important to note is that this causes no errors.

Comment: Where do the vertical lines joining x and y come from? I thought they might be artefacts, but I can reproduce them even zooming in. EDIT: Oh. Maybe you just need to put y a bit higher?

Comment: Thanks for this! How do I get your spath3 library though? I'm getting ```! Package tikz Error: I did not find the tikz library 'spath3'. I looked for fi
les named tikzlibraryspath3.code.tex and pgflibraryspath3.code.tex, but neither
 could be found in the current texmf trees..```.

Comment: Is this included by default into tikz, and I don't have the latest version? Or do I need to download some file?

Comment: @AndiBauer Not part of Ti*k*Z, but included in TeX Live, for example, and available on CTAN.

Comment: Alright! Seems like TeX Live 2019 is too old of a version?

Comment: @AndiBauer Yes, the TikZ library overlay was added to the package in 2021, so you'll need a TeXLive of at least 2022.  Alternatively, you can get the latest stable version direct from CTAN at https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3 or the latest development version from github at https://github.com/loopspace/spath3

Comment: @cfr Yeah, or swap the `b` for a letter without ascenders or descenders.  I was keeping the same separation between the examples but wanting to split the last example in the original file.  Also, the `only if drawable` should use `\tl_put_right:Nn` instead of `\tl_set:Nn` to avoid clobbering that token list if some other routine has put something there.

Comment: I switched to TeXlive 23 now, and it all compiles! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Getting lots of ```Missing character: There is no y in font nullfont!``` warnings now, but they don't seem to be related to you code.

Comment: @AndiBauer That happens when some non-tikz stuff gets put in a tikz picture.  You should try commenting out pieces to narrow down what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it by using a coordinate rather than a node. For example, you can specify one of the node's anchors rather than the node itself.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{
  mysnake/.style={postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=1pt,segment length=3pt}}},
  allsnake/.style={mysnake,every edge/.style=mysnake},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % works
  \path[mysnake] (0,0)--++(1,0);
  % compiles but doesn't decorate
  \path[mysnake] (0,0.4)edge[]++(1,0);
  % decorates both the path and the edges
  \path[allsnake] (0,0.8)edge[]++(1,0) (0,1.2)--++(1,0);
  % this is fine as well:
  \path[allsnake] (0,1.6)edge[]++(1,0);
  % this doesn't compile though:
  \node[draw] (x) at (0,2){a};
  \path[allsnake] (x.east) edge[] ++(1,0);
%   % this doesn't compile either:
  \path[mysnake] (x.east)edge[]++(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: decorated paths from nodes]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I was looking for a more "general" fix. My situation is that I have a large file with say 1000 tikz figures that all use paths with a style ```mylinestyle``` that is defined as ```dashed``` in the moment. And now I would like to redefine ```mylinestyle``` such that all the dashed lines are squiggly lines, without editing all the individual figures.